# Unintended autocomplete or alias in Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh, autocomplete

There is a "strange" autocomplete function in my macbook.
If I try to type "`ps -aux`" in terminal (iTerm or TotalTerminal)
with the hit of "s" in ps, automatically this happens:

```
"ps -p $$
# Tells the shell what you are using"
```

There is no alias stored in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.
Which program could run this autocomplete?
The "funny" thing is, when I type this, also here in this window, the autocomplete apears.

Any suggestions, ideas?

---

## 10.9.2 (13C32) Development version.

But with 10.9.1 was the same.

This autocomplete start immediately in Search, in Alfred, in Notes, in Numbers, in R(!) ...

The combination of "p" and "s" produces -without "Enter": "ps -p $$

## Tells the shell what you are using"

There must be a location/config-file ...

The challenge is: Find the file/location which stores this command/autocomplete.

Comment: Does it also appear when you type in a text shell outside the XWindows environment --- if that is possible on OSX? Under Linux you can reach these virtual terminals using e.g. `ctrl-alt-F1`.

Comment: I run OS X (10.9.2)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you have 10.9.2? Are you running a beta version? I have 10.9.1 and seem to be totally up to date. Did this happen only with the upgrade to 10.9.2?

Comment: OK. As I found out OSX does not seem to have text (or "virtual") terminals. So you cannot test what I suggested. Sorry about. What about logging into the machine from the outside? Does this generate the same effect?

Comment: Does it help if you enter a backslash first, like this: `\ps -aux` ?

Comment: Open *System Preferences*, select the *Language & Text* preference pane, the *Text* tab, and look for a placeholder `ps` to be replaced with the text you wrote. Alternatively, are you using a tool such as TextExpander?

Comment: The reason and solution: Dash (http://kapeli.com/dash).
Dash autocompletes stored snippets! puh.